# JPARepository - updating entity does not work after calling restTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having issue to persist an updated entity after calling RestTemplate to get the data and save it into an existing entity:

TaskResponse task -= restTemplate.postForEntity(url, taskRequest, TaskResponse.class).getBody;

String extProjectIdent = task.getProcessInstance() + '~' + task.getTaskId();
Long projectId = taskRequest.getProjectEntity().getId();

ProjectEntity projectEntity = projectRepo.findById(projectId).get();
projectEntity.setExtProjectId(extProjectIdent);

projectRepo.save(projectEntity);

I don't have any exception thrown , does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you rewrite you code in a try catch  and show what you get?

Comment: I found the solution myself the field ExtProjectId was set to updatable=false .

Comment: Thank you Arthurofos, I am trying to build the repository now and see if it will work after changing updatable from the class domain..

Comment: If any problem, after that lets me know